# How to predict Precision, Recall and F1 score after training SSD

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, single-shot-detector

I am new to deep learning and I want to be able to evaluate the model which underwent training for certain epochs using F1 score. I believe it requires the calculation of precision and recall first.

The model trained is SSD-300-Tensorflow. Is there a code or something that can produce these results? I am not using sci-kit or anything as I am not sure if that is required to calculate the score but any guidance is appreciated.

There is a file for evaluation in folder tf_extended called metrics.py which has a code for precision and recall. After training my files, I have the checkpoints in logs folder. How can I calculate my metrics? I am using Google collab due to hardware limitations (GPU issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Tensorflow Object Detection API, it provides a way for running model evaluation that can be configured for different metrics. A tutorial on how to do this is [here](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#evaluating-the-model-optional).

The COCO evaluation metrics includes analogous measures of precision and recall for object detection use cases. A good overview of these metrics is [here](https://blog.zenggyu.com/en/post/2018-12-16/an-introduction-to-evaluation-metrics-for-object-detection/). The concepts of precision and recall need to be adapted somewhat for object detection scenarios because you have to define "how closely" a predicted bounding box needs to match the ground truth bounding box to be considered a true positive.

I am not certain what the analog for F1 score would be for object detection scenarios. Typically, I have seen models compared using mAP as the single evaluation metric.

Comment: I could set up tensorflow but it does not provide an interface with F1 score and Precision, recall

Comment: I have updated my question. How can I use metrics.py for generating precision and recall for F1 score? The tensorboard provides everything but the metrics I need. @chubbs

Comment: Could you clarify, what code are you working with?

If it is https://github.com/balancap/SSD-Tensorflow, then I see a note in the readme about how to run evaluation from a checkpoint here: https://github.com/balancap/SSD-Tensorflow#evaluation-on-pascal-voc-2007.

Comment: I followed that. There is a file called eval_ssd_network that has parameters for calculating mAP. It has recall and precision together. How can I find Recall and Precision separately @chubbs?

Comment: Hrm, I'm not exactly certain what you mean. Precision and recall are linked through the confidence score. If you are just trying to get the values out separately, it looks like they are unpacked here: https://github.com/balancap/SSD-Tensorflow/blob/master/eval_ssd_network.py#L250

Comment: I tried printing the values which are probably in tf.dense format and therefore could not be unpacked

Answer (score -1):

You should first calculate False positive, False negatives, True positive and True negatives. To obtain these values you must evaluate your model with test dataset. [This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) might help

with these formulas you can calculate precision and recall and here is some example code:

```
y_hat = []
y = []
threshold = 0.5
for data, label in test_dataset:
    y_hat.extend(model.predict(data))
    y.extend(label.numpy()[:, 1])
    y_hat = np.asarray(y_hat)
    y = np.asarray(y)
    m = len(y)
    y_hat = np.asarray([1 if i > threshold else 0 for i in y_hat[:, 1]])
    true_positive = np.logical_and(y, y_hat).sum()
    true_negative = np.logical_and(np.logical_not(y_hat), np.logical_not(y)).sum()
    false_positive = np.logical_and(np.logical_not(y), y_hat).sum()
    false_negative = np.logical_and(np.logical_not(y_hat), y).sum()
    total = true_positive + true_negative + false_negative + false_positive
    assert total == m
    precision = true_positive / (true_positive + false_positive)
    recall = true_positive / (true_positive + false_negative)
    accuracy = (true_positive + true_negative) / total
    f1score = 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall)
```

Comment: there is already a metrics.py which has some code for precision and recall but I am not sure how to use that for generating the metrics

Comment: If you can share some codes or tell about your project (like your are using object detection api or other part of tensorflow) i can help you better. And it would be better if you do not downvote my answer :-)